# Interior Shadow Catcher

Tags: shadows, shadowcatcher

I've got an issue that I haven't been able to solve so I'm turning to the community for help. Here's my objective. I'm attempting to recreate an interior real estate photo to virtually stage with CG furniture. Once done, I in theory would set the room as a shadow catcher and render out just the furniture and shadows. Doing this in practice works okay expect for a very obvious bug that I can't get around. Once I set the room as a shadow catcher in the object properties, additional light seemingly passes through what should be a solid wall to cast unrealistic shadows across the floor and all realistic bounce light shadows from the window are seemingly gone.

Here's a visual example of what I'm talking about

The first image has the correct shadows that I want, but the room is still rendered. Note I only want the furniture and shadows.
[image]

The second image is when the room is set to shadow catcher which produces incorrect shadows. It's almost like the exterior sun is passing through what should be the wall and is casting long dark shadows across the floor.
[image]

I've tried blocking the sun with a plane outside the room, but this also casts dark shadows across the shadow catcher. I've tried compositing just the shadow data from the rendered layer, but all light bouncing within the room is considered a shadow since the sun originates outside. The only way I've been able to "properly" render out the furniture and shadows is by faking bounce light with an area light inside the room, which doesn't look good and defeats the purpose of recreating the existing sunlight to light the entire room.

Is there any way to get around this inherent bug with the shadow catcher function? Can Blender in this current state even accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: This is not a bug, since it is working as intended, but rather an opening for a feature request.